# What's Fibre Channel?

Tags: fibre-channel

i don't understand if the technology 'fibre channel' is something 'software' or something 'hardware' (fibre optics connection) ?
Can i create a fibre-channel san using 'some' pieces of existent hardware (like old computer with linux  or similar) ?
Thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibre_Channel

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrapheap_Challenge

Comment: @Sirch Oh, that's mean and a good laugh...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibre_Channel

At the most basic level it's a signaling protocol.  It can run over copper or fiber.  So its a combo of hardware and software.  Hardware to terminate and transmit traffic and software to interpret that traffic.  In my experience (SMB) it works much like a NIC just a different addressing method and certainly different/more expensive hardware.